# Stream video with FFMPEG, "Output file does not contain any stream"

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, video-streaming, h.264

I would like to stream an H.264 encoded elementary stream wrapped in RTP headers to a port using FFMPEG.

I have tried the following command lines to no avail...

```
ffmpeg -i 1080p_1.h264 -f rtp -vcodec libx264 rtp://localhost:4000
```

and get the following error:

> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 1080p_1.h264 -f rtp -vcodec copy rtp://localhost:4000
```

with the same error.

If I do a conversion with WinFF it seems to work, and the Elecard Stream Analyzer seems to indicate SPS and PPS NAL Units for stream #0.

Comment: Can FFMPEG even work on such raw Annex B streams? What conversion with WinFF are you doing?

Comment: re: ...what conversion? the WMV preset

Comment: It's the same error as this, but there's no answer to:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007882/ffmpeg-rtp-streaming-error